# Glitch in automatic result of a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

the code I am currently working fine as expected. However, there is small error in the result. I am trying to calculate the total price based on price of product and Quantity.(Multiplication)
In the output, the result not coming automatically if the quantity is 1. I have to select other value and again have to select the quantity as 1, then it shows the correct total price. This happens due to i choose the default value for quantity is 1. I am just curious about what if i want only numbers to be displayed without the "please select" items like that.Any help is appreciated

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript">
function multiply() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Quantityddl").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("txtPrice").value;
    if (x != null & y != null) {
        document.getElementById("txtTotalPrice").value = parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);
    }
}
</script>
```

ASP Code for Dropdown and textbox fields:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Quantityddl" runat="server" onchange="multiply()">
    <asp:ListItem Selected = "True" Value = "1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "5">5</asp:ListItem>

<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" onchange="multiply()"</asp:TextBox>
</td>

<td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="NEXT" onchange="multiply()" />
</td>
```

Comment: @mplungjan yah i tried in that way and it works. But, I am just curious about what if i want only numbers to be displayed without the "please select" items like that. Thank you

Comment: Change the onchange in the text field to onkeyup and the onchange of the button to onclick

Comment: Please see my amended answer. I do not think your own solution is optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change the onchange in the text field to onkeyup and the onchange of the button to onclick
2. if you want the select to also work, you MUST add a please select or use onload to store the selected value of the select.

The reason is that onchange of buttons do not make sense and onchange of text fields needs a blur to trigger

I would also add radix and test the fields for actual numbers

```
function isNumeric(n) { return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);}

function multiply() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Quantityddl").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("txtPrice").value;
  if (isNumeric(x) && isNumeric(y)) {
    document.getElementById("txtTotalPrice").value = parseInt(x,10) * parseInt(y,10);
  }
}
```

using

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Quantityddl" runat="server" onchange="multiply()">
    <asp:ListItem Selected = "True" Value = "">Please select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value = "5">5</asp:ListItem>

<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" onkeyup="multiply()"</asp:TextBox>
</td>

<td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="NEXT" onclick="multiply()" />
</td>
```